# Complex diffeomorphism and a domain being Polygon

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I've been studying the lecture notes of 246A taught by Prof. Terence Tao.

- https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2016/10/18/246a-notes-5-conformal-mapping/#more-9481

But I am stuck at understanding this sentence,

> in particular, such diffeomorphisms exist if (the domain of such diffeomorphism)U is a polygon

** Line 3 of Section 4. Schwarz-Christoffel mappings

Could anyone tell me why so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polygon $U$ is simply connected and omits at least one point, so there is a bijective Riemann map from the disk to $U$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! Sorry, what do you mean by "omits at least one point"?

Comment: The polygon is not the entire plane (the complement of the polygon is nonempty).This nitpicky detail is mentioned because the entire plane is the one exception to the principle that simply-connected sets  can be mapped to the unit disk biholomorphically.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your explanation totally makes sense!